# Retrieving OrientVertex Objects from OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm having trouble with the Graph API of OrientDB in Java.

**Problem:**

Retrieve Vertices (OrientVertex or Vertex?) from a persistent local graph database with several Vertices/Edges created via the console.

So for, I've been able to query the database from what I now think is the Document API using

```
graph = factory.getTx();
String string = String.format("select * from V where name like \"%s\"", criteria);
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<OrientVertex>(string);
List<OrientDocument> results = graph.getRawGraph().command(query).execute();
```

But this will not work for Vertices. **How do I run queries that return a list of Vertices in my database?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specifically, the documentation is very good on how to write the queries, but not so clear on how to actually **use** the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are using the Graph API. After calling `getRawGraph()` you are **not** working with the Graph API any more, but with the Document API (method name is a little bit confusing).

Having a reference to the `OrientGraph` there are several possibilities

- Using `orientGraph#getVertex*(..)` / `orientGraph#getVertices*(..)`style of methods
- Using a Query object: `orientGraph#query().has("key", value).vertices()`
- Using the [gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) query language
- Using `orientGraph#command(...).execute()`. In this case the command is executed **outside** the transaction (thanks @wolf4ood)

Comment: The `getVertex` and `getVertices` seem to return Blueprint `Vertex` data types, not `OrientVertex` which means I lose some of the advantages of `OrientVertex`. I'll try the query object and report back. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `graph.query().has("name").vertices()` seems to return `Iterable<Vertex>`. Is there no way to get OrientVertex objects out of the database?

Comment: It is simple to cast them to `OrientVertex`. They return `Vertex` because some methods implement the Blueprints API. Other methods (labelled with "Blueprints Extension") return OrientVertex. Take a look at the API doc. So the **implementation** is `OrientVertex` in all cases!

Comment: @rmuller is there any way to use graph.query() by specified class, not by all V objects?

Comment: @heroin Not that I am aware of. Should use `getVertices(String label, String[] iKey, Object[] iValue)`

Comment: Thanks, it is the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid getting the rawGraph and executed command directly with orientGraph
and returns an iterable of OrientVertex

like this :

```
graph = factory.getTx();
String query = String.format("select * from V where name like \"%s\"", criteria);
OSQLSynchQuery<OrientVertex> qr = new OSQLSynchQuery<OrientVertex>(query);
Iterable<OrientVertex> vertices = graph.command(qr).execute();
```

Comment: Note that if using `orientGraph#command(...)`, the command is executed **outside** the transaction.

Comment: This would be better, but execution outside of the transaction doesn't sound like a good thing. Is there an instance in which i **should** be using this method? Doesn't this break ACID principals? I can still write a SQL query and use wildcards with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we want to retrieve Vertices specially based on other properties like **names** ,**age** etc so, I used ***getVertices()*** method to get the iterator and then extracted the vertex since ***getVertexByKey()*** is deprecated now.The code is:
`Vertex v2=graph.getVertices("name","Business").iterator().next();`

So we just got the vertex without knowing the RID of the record.
I don't know whether this is the best method to do this but it does the job.